# when checkbox has jQuery assigned to it, tick no longer works

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, textinput

I'm having a strange problem with a checkbox on one of my pages. Basically I have a bit of jQuery ( below ) assigned to it so that when it is clicked the fields below fill up with the same info as above ( same as billing info kinda thing ) However when this jQuery is assigned to it the tick fails to fill the checkbox.

I have tried various methods to get the checkbox to tick manually but to no avail, could anyone shed some light on this problem?

```
$('#sameasbilling').toggle(function() {

    //assign value of billing firstname text input to variable 'firstname'
    var firstname = $('input[name=billingfirstnames]').val();

    //insert value of 'firstname' into delivery text input
    $('input[name=deliveryfirstnames]').val(firstname);

    $('#sameasbilling').attr("checked", checked);

},function() {
    $('input[name=deliveryfirstnames]').val("");
});
```

The jQuery I have tried ( plus many variants of those two lines ) to get the ticker to work manually is below, neither of them have worked.

```
$('#sameasbilling').attr("checked", checked);

$('#sameasbilling').prop("checked", true);
```

Thanks in advance. Dan.

Comment: The problem is more in the JQuery `toggle()` event I think. Try changing the toggle to a `click()` event and see if this helps?

Comment: Thanks, turns out that the problem was with the .toggle function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `toggle()` method is incorrect in this instance, use `click()` instead. Try this:

```
$('#sameasbilling').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //assign value of billing firstname text input to variable 'firstname'
        var firstname = $('input[name=billingfirstnames]').val();

        //insert value of 'firstname' into delivery text input
        $('input[name=deliveryfirstnames]').val(firstname);
    }
    else {
         $('input[name=deliveryfirstnames]').val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, worked perfectly. So was my .toggle function malformed or was the .toggle what caused the problem, something in the way the .toggle function works perhaps?

Comment: The `toggle()` syntax itself was correct, but placing it inside a `click()` handler effectively meant the code was being run twice.